# What is the best way to google for problems involving actual stack overflow without false positives caused by stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion

If I want to search google for programming problems which result in a stack overflow then a naive search might include every item on the site 'stackoverflow.com'

Including `-stackoverflow` in the keywords excludes all results from the stackoverflow sites. This may be not ideal.

Searching stackoverflow itself excludes the rest of the internet and may include false positives anyway.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: You can search [at the site itself](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=stack+overflow), this seems to get better results.

Comment: Doesn't this belong on meta.google.com? ;P

Comment: So, is your question how to search Google without picking up results from stackoverflow.com? Because asking that *on stackoverflow.com* seems a bit backward...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan They don't want to filter out results *from* stackoverflow.com, they want to filter out results *about* stackoverflow.com, or results that only appear because they're on stackoverflow.com but aren't actually related to stack overflow exceptions, i.e. [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=stack+overflow&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: `code:stackoverflow` will limit your results on Stack Overflow to code. Of course, too many people misuse code format, so I'm going on an edit spree to make this more effective.

Comment: You could always try magic... that is, of course, the best way to do anything

Comment: you may want to try http://stackse.com

Comment: `stack overflow -site:stackoverflow.com` gives some results.. although not from stackoverflow.com...

Comment: Google for the exception code `0xC00000FD`

Comment: Do you specifically want to use Google, or is this shorthand for "search the web using a search engine"?

Comment: Another question is... what's there too Google about stack overflows in the first place?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Depending on the language/framework, you can try using a part of the error message. For example, `stackoverflowexception site:stackoverflow.com` gives pretty good results for stack overflow problems in the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 7):

I have never had any major issue with false positives when I have googled "stackoverflow [error text here]", typically useful results are right at the top of the list.

Answer (score 5):

I would do two searches. The one you already mentioned that excludes SO from the google search, then a search within SO and taking into account the tag mentioned bu Aaroninus ([stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow)).

Cumbersome, yes, but you get more meaningful results than just typing "Stack Overflow" on Google.

Comment: Refining a search is by definition cumbersome. Don't know why you're down-voted...

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised no one mentions Google chromes builtin feature. Type stackoverflow.com (typical just hit enter for first hit)

[image]

And press tab, now the search is passed to stackoverflow

[image]

Comment: Yeah except that this is exactly what the OP is trying to prevent. He just wants to search for "stackoverflow" and not get **only** a list of random results from the site named Stack Overflow. But not exclude all items either; Stack Overflow questions about stackoverflows are still relevant.